# flutterflow no se me ven los textos en web

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, dart

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bORHd.jpg En celular se me ve asi
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/woo1U.png pero en web, selecciono mi celular y se ve bien

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Que onda bro, yo tenia un problema similar y era el tema de la traducción de la app.

Es decir, mi app esta en español y en ingles sin embargo en este ultimo no he cambiado textos como tal y por ello salen como si no hubiese nada.

tienes dos soluciones:

1- Cambiar el lenguaje del celular (o en el dispositivo en el que simulas la app) en el cual instalaste el apk.

2- Al momento de hacer la app, hacer los textos en español e ingles (u otro idioma).

[image: Captura opciones traducción]